# Windows RPC programming error: LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol RPCServerListen

Tags: c, rpc

I am learning C Windows RPC programming. Here is the source code for a dummy RPC Server I wrote and compiled without errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "md5_h.h"
#include "rpc.h"
#include "rpcndr.h"

int main() {
  RPC_STATUS status;

  status = RpcServerUseProtseqEp(
    (RPC_WSTR)("ncacn_ip_tcp"),
    RPC_C_PROTSEQ_MAX_REQS_DEFAULT,
    (RPC_WSTR)("9191"),
    NULL);
if (status) { exit(status); }

status = RpcServerRegisterIf(
    md5_v1_0_c_ifspec,
    NULL,
    NULL);
if (status) { exit(status); }

status = RpcServerListen(
    1,
    RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT,
    FALSE);
if (status) { exit(status); }

return 0;
}

void __RPC_USER midl_user_free(void* p) {
  free(p);
}

void md5(const unsigned char* szMsg) {
  printf("voila %s\n", szMsg);
}
```

The midl files get compiled without errors as well. The MIDL-compilation produces `md5_s.c` and `md5_c.c` as expected. Here is `md5.idl` file if needed:

```
[
uuid(D86FBC01-D6A7-4941-9243-07A4EC65E8CB),
    version(1.0),
]
interface md5
{
  void md5([in, string] const char* szMsg);
};
```

During the Linkage stage the following errors are produced:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RpcServerListen referenced in function main
```

I have same errors for every RPC-specific functions, such as `RpcServerRegisterIf` or `RpcServerUseProtseqEp`.  I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

I think this comes from a missing include; but I can't figure which one. I tried to include `rpc.h`, without any change.

Do I have to include in my project the produced `md5_s.c`? I have tried so without resolving anything.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link against Rpcrt4.lib.
If you are using visual studio, add it in the Project ->  Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue I was having; But how the hell did you figure that out?

Comment: @philippe This was a link error. Not all .lib files are included in the default list. So from time to time, you need to add the additional .lib files. Example: winsock, shell APIs and e.t.c. require the .lib files to be added manually. When the linker emits errors, checkout the footer notes in MSDN, it lists the library file to use, Rpcrt4.lib in this case.